# Cocos2d C++ equivalent of objective-c function CCCallBlock actionWithBlock

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, code-translation

Does anyone knows what is the c++ equivalent of objective-C CCCallBlock actionWithBlock ?

```
[CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{ ... code here .. }]
```

Answer (score 1):

In the cocos2d-x, you can't use `CCCallBlock`, instead, you can use `cocos2d::CallFunc` and since cocos2d-x v3.0, you can use C++11 features, so it would be pretty much simple.

If the code is like this,

```
id block = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
             [do func1]
             [do func2]
           }];
```

then, it would be like the following code.

```
auto block = cocos2d::CallFunc::create(
                    [&](){
                          func1();
                          func2();
                     });
```

And then you can make the spite do block as like the one with `CCCallBlock`.